# Why did Frodo need to go it alone, leaving Aragorn and Legolas behind?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

Why does Frodo have to fly solo without the others at the end of [*The Fellowship of the Ring*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/)? Especially *Aragorn* and *Legolas* both seem like incredible assassins/bodyguards and basically immune to the draw of the ring.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Frodo saw the effect the ring had on Boromir (Sean Bean), and knew that eventually it would corrupt the rest of the Fellowship. *No one* is immune to the ring. Even, Gandalf and Galadriel refused to touch it. Frodo as a hobbit, is a bit resistant to the ring, but not completely impervious to it's influence. This is something that Lady Galadriel had foretold (emphasis mine).

> **Galadriel:** It is what will come to pass, If you should fail. The
>   Fellowship is breaking, it has already begun. He will try to take the
>   Ring, you know of whom I speak. One by one, it will destroy **them**.

So Frodo knew that if he was to have a real chance at destroying the ring he would need to do this by himself and carry the burden alone. Of course Sam had other ideas.

> **Galadriel**: You are a Ring-bearer, Frodo. To bear a Ring of Power is to be alone.

Comment: +1 This is basically it - No one is immune to the ring. Except maybe Tom Bombadil.

Comment: For a little expansion in the books Bombadil is discussed and discarded because he'd probably just forget about it and lose it...